# Is there a way to differentiate with jQuery beforeunload event types?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I was wondering how can those 3 transition events below can be handled in jQuery separately:

- cancel loading page
- refresh page
- unload resources
- move to another resource

At the moment I am using the 'beforeunload' event but it clearly does not fit all my needs, specifically I cannot distinguish different type of 'beforeunload':

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function () {
  // doing my stuff here
});
```

[EDIT]
Higher level related problems:

- I would like that during the loading of the new resource / page to display a loading spinner / panel but upon loading completion perform a fadeout on that page (body) (I already handle the fadein on the jQuery onready event). How can I achieve that? Is there for example a workaround with the server side and leveraging cookies + AJAX with ASP.NET?
- I would like to display a message (e.g. bootstrap modal) when user is cancelling the loading process, is there also any workaround that can leverage the server side?

Comment: No there is no way to distinguish strictly from the event itself. What higher level problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @charlietfl I updated the description, let me know if you need more details.

Comment: You can't control another page. All the javascript in current page is gone when new page loads